# Create a python dictionary containig file addresses as keys, and the content as its values?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

The Code i have so far:`

```
import os
import xlrd
import re
import sys  
from collections import OrderedDict
import json


reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
#####the keyword should be "ab_"

rootdir = 'C:\Users\'

variable_count = 1

name = re.compile('ab_')
excel_files = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if ".xlsx" in file:
            excel_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file)) #list of excel files

variables_list = []
s = [] 
dict_files = {}
dict_variables = {}
for items in excel_files:
    for sh in xlrd.open_workbook(items).sheets():  
        for row in range(sh.nrows):
            for col in range(sh.ncols):
                myCell = sh.cell(row, col)
                if name.search(str(myCell.value)):
                    excel_keyword = []
                    excel_keyword.append(items)
                    dict_files[items] = None
for keys in dict_files:
    for sh in xlrd.open_workbook(keys).sheets():  
        for row in range(sh.nrows):
            for col in range(sh.ncols):
                myCell = sh.cell(row, col)
                if name.search(str(myCell.value)):
                    dict_variables[variable_count] = str(myCell.value)
                    variable_count += 1
                    dict_files[keys] = dict_variables



                        #print dict_variables.values()
                    #print dict_files


f = open(r"Results_variables.json", "w")
json.dump(dict_files, f, indent=3, sort_keys=True)              ###indent and sort_keys for pretty printing###
f.close()`
```

However, this Code finds all the Excel addresses and the cell values containing "ab_" and append all the cell values found to each of the keys. What i Need is to append to each key is only the cells containing "ab_" found inside this key address.

Current Output:

```
{

 "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx":
    1: "ab_blue"
    2: "ab_red"
    3: "ab_white"
    4: "ab_yellow"
    5: "ab_purple"
 "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx":
    1: "ab_blue"
    2: "ab_red"
    3: "ab_white"
    4: "ab_yellow"
    5: "ab_purple"
 "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx":
    1: "ab_blue"
    2: "ab_red"
    3: "ab_white"
    4: "ab_yellow"
    5: "ab_purple"
 "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx":
    1: "ab_blue"
    2: "ab_red"
    3: "ab_white"
    4: "ab_yellow"
    5: "ab_purple"

}
```

Intended Output:

```
{

 "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx":
    1: "ab_blue"
 "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx":
    1: "ab_red"
 "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx":
    1: "ab_white"
 "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx":
    1: "ab_yellow"
    2: "ab_purple"

}
```

Comment: you want `"C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx"` as a key more than once? Keys are unique in a python dictionary. You'll need to clarify what you want. It's hard to see the nesting in your Current Output / Intended Output: without the braces / commas

Comment: Nope, i want it just once. There will be two dictionaries. The first one (dict_files) will contain the addresses as keys and the Dictionary dict_variables as values. What i need is that the value of the key "C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx" (the dict_variables) will contain only the cell values including the Keyword "ab_" found inside that file("C:\\Users\\house_1.xlsx" ). The same of other files.